# If Moon escapes to infinite distance from Earth gravity, will its gravity change?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, estimation, planets

As we know that gravity of earth influences Moon gravity and vice-versa. Suppose, Moon escapes to infinite distance where there is no other object to affect it, will we weight higher there? If yes how mass increases as per $g= GM/r^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center of mass of the Moon is in free-fall around the Earth and does not experience any gravity. If removed into empty space there is no difference there.

However, a point on the surface of the moon experiences a bit of residual gravitational force from Earth since it is not in free fall: this is called a [tidal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force). This force points towards Earth on the near side, and away from Earth on the far side. Were the moon removed to empty space the tidal force would disappear. It is not large: $2.44\times 10^{-5}$ N/kg, which can be compared to normal lunar gravity, 1.62 N/kg.

But, yes, if the moon escapes you will weigh more on the former near and far sides, and the same along the midline.